# Prevent program from change system settings in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I run a steam program called Live2DViewerEX. It automatically turn on a system setting which is `Animate controls and elements inside windows`.

I have talked to the developer. But if they don't care what I said. How can I do to prevent the program from changing the setting.

Comment: @John Do you mean it is impossible?

Comment: I don't even know how they did it. The way I found to change this setting is to use registry command and it is not immediate. relogging or reboot is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three methods to
[How to Enable or Disable Animate Controls and Elements Inside Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/126844-enable-disable-animate-controls-elements-inside-windows.html)
that don't involve reboot or logout.

You can't stop Live2DViewerEX from doing what it's doing.
If you wish to continue playing it, you'll need to keep on unsetting
this option after each game.

Another option is to install the game inside a sandbox so it cannot
affect the running system. You could use
[Sandboxie](https://sandboxie-plus.com/downloads/)
for example.

Comment: Or run a Windows 10 virtual machine *inside* of Windows 10. That, or using a sandbox, might give additional protection -- since one might be wary of *any* software, including a game, that makes changes to *system* settings without your permission.